# Cassandra: Exiting due to error while processing commit log during initialization

Tags: cassandra

I was loading a large CSV into Cassandra using cassandra-loader.

The VM ran out of disk space during this process and crashed. I allocated more disk space to the VM and tried starting cassandra but it refused to start due to problems with SSTables and commit log.

I could not run `nodetool repair` as it is only works when the node is online. 
I ran `sstablescrub` which took about 1 hour to finish. So I thought it might have fixed it.

But I still get this error in `system.log`

```
ERROR [SSTableBatchOpen:4] 2015-10-23 18:57:45,035 SSTableReader.java:506 - Corrupt sstable /var/lib/cassandra/data/keyspace1/location-777a33d0772911e597a98b820c5778a4/la-1709-big=[TOC.txt, CompressionInfo.db, Statistics.db, Digest.adler32, Data.db, Index.db, Filter.db]; skipping table
org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.CorruptSSTableException: java.io.EOFException
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.CompressionMetadata.<init>(CompressionMetadata.java:125) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.CompressionMetadata.create(CompressionMetadata.java:86) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.CompressedSegmentedFile$Builder.metadata(CompressedSegmentedFile.java:142) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.CompressedPoolingSegmentedFile$Builder.complete(CompressedPoolingSegmentedFile.java:101) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.SegmentedFile$Builder.complete(SegmentedFile.java:187) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.SegmentedFile$Builder.complete(SegmentedFile.java:179) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.SSTableReader.load(SSTableReader.java:703) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.SSTableReader.load(SSTableReader.java:664) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.SSTableReader.open(SSTableReader.java:458) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.SSTableReader.open(SSTableReader.java:363) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.SSTableReader$4.run(SSTableReader.java:501) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_60]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_60]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_60]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_60]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_60]
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: null
        at java.io.DataInputStream.readUnsignedShort(DataInputStream.java:340) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
        at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:589) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
        at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:564) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.CompressionMetadata.<init>(CompressionMetadata.java:96) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
        ... 15 common frames omitted
INFO  [main] 2015-10-23 18:57:45,193 ColumnFamilyStore.java:382 - Initializing system_auth.role_permissions
INFO  [main] 2015-10-23 18:57:45,201 ColumnFamilyStore.java:382 - Initializing system_auth.resource_role_permissons_index
INFO  [main] 2015-10-23 18:57:45,213 ColumnFamilyStore.java:382 - Initializing system_auth.roles
INFO  [main] 2015-10-23 18:57:45,233 ColumnFamilyStore.java:382 - Initializing system_auth.role_members
INFO  [main] 2015-10-23 18:57:45,240 ColumnFamilyStore.java:382 - Initializing system_traces.sessions
INFO  [main] 2015-10-23 18:57:45,252 ColumnFamilyStore.java:382 - Initializing system_traces.events
INFO  [main] 2015-10-23 18:57:45,265 ColumnFamilyStore.java:382 - Initializing simplex.songs
INFO  [main] 2015-10-23 18:57:45,276 ColumnFamilyStore.java:382 - Initializing simplex.playlists
INFO  [pool-2-thread-1] 2015-10-23 18:57:45,289 AutoSavingCache.java:187 - reading saved cache /var/lib/cassandra/saved_caches/KeyCache-ca.db
INFO  [pool-2-thread-1] 2015-10-23 18:57:45,313 AutoSavingCache.java:163 - Completed loading (25 ms; 36 keys) KeyCache cache
INFO  [main] 2015-10-23 18:57:45,351 CommitLog.java:168 - Replaying /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-5-1445578022702.log, /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-5-1445578022703.log, /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-5-1445578022704.log, /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-5-1445578022705.log, /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-5-1445578022706.log, /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-5-1445578022707.log, /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-5-1445578022708.log, /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-5-1445578022709.log, /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-5-1445578022710.log, /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-5-1445578022712.log, /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-5-1445578022713.log, /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-5-1445578022714.log, /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-5-1445578022715.log, /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-5-1445578022716.log, /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-5-1445578022717.log, /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-5-1445578022719.log, /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-5-1445578022720.log, /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-5-1445578022721.log, /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-5-1445578022722.log, /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-5-1445578022723.log, /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-5-1445578022724.log, /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-5-1445578022725.log, /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-5-1445578022727.log, /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-5-1445578022728.log, /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-5-1445578022730.log, /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-5-1445578022731.log, /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-5-1445578022732.log, /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-5-1445578022733.log, /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-5-1445578022734.log, /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-5-1445578022736.log, /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-5-1445578022738.log, /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-5-1445578022740.log, /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-5-1445578022741.log, /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-5-1445578022743.log, /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-5-1445578022744.log, /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-5-1445578022745.log, /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-5-1445578022746.log, /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-5-1445578022748.log, /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-5-1445578022749.log, /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-5-1445578022750.log, /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-5-1445578022751.log, /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-5-1445578022752.log, /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-5-1445578022753.log, /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-5-1445578022755.log, /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-5-1445578022756.log, /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-5-1445578022758.log, /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-5-1445578022759.log, /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-5-1445578022760.log, /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-5-1445578022761.log, /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-5-1445578022763.log, /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-5-1445578022764.log, /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-5-1445578022765.log, /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-5-1445578022766.log, /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-5-1445578022767.log, /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-5-1445578022768.log, /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-5-1445578022769.log, /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-5-1445578022770.log, /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-5-1445578022771.log, /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-5-1445578022772.log, /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-5-1445578022773.log, /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-5-1445578022774.log, /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-5-1445578022775.log, /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-5-1445578022776.log, /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-5-1445588991268.log, /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-5-1445589094722.log, /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-5-1445589149527.log, /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-5-1445595828633.log, /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-5-1445595898055.log, /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-5-1445596033717.log, /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-5-1445596400441.log, /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-5-1445596601854.log, /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-5-1445598032544.log, /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-5-1445598758663.log, /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-5-1445601112953.log, /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-5-1445601937334.log, /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-5-1445601985416.log, /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-5-1445604504389.log, /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-5-1445606516196.log
ERROR [main] 2015-10-23 18:59:05,091 JVMStabilityInspector.java:78 - Exiting due to error while processing commit log during initialization.
org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLogReplayer$CommitLogReplayException: Mutation checksum failure at 4110758 in CommitLog-5-1445578022776.log
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLogReplayer.handleReplayError(CommitLogReplayer.java:622) [apache-cassandra-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLogReplayer.replaySyncSection(CommitLogReplayer.java:492) [apache-cassandra-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLogReplayer.recover(CommitLogReplayer.java:388) [apache-cassandra-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLogReplayer.recover(CommitLogReplayer.java:147) [apache-cassandra-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLog.recover(CommitLog.java:189) [apache-cassandra-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLog.recover(CommitLog.java:169) [apache-cassandra-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:273) [apache-cassandra-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:513) [apache-cassandra-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:622) [apache-cassandra-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
Exiting due to error while processing commit log during initialization.
```

How do I fix this? This is test data, I am okay with losing it. How would one handle this in production to avoid data loss?

Tried setting `disk_failure_policy: ignore` so that I could run `nodetool repair` once the server is up. But the server does not start even with this setting.

I am operating a single node and replication factor is 1. Would having more nodes and a >1 replication factor enabled me to fix an issue like this without data loss?

I am using Cassandra 2.2.3

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Having some replication would surely help you to fix this without data loss but it would come with a price.

Despite all your effort you cannot manage to recover your corrupted sstable. So you decide to remove it from your file system to start Cassandra again. If you do not have replication your data is lost. But if you have replication on the cluster, you can possibly fetch the data from other nodes. That is what `nodetool repair` do !

So `nodetool repair` does not repair corrupted sstable. Basically`nodetool repair` compare tables from node to node to find missing or inconsistent data and then repair it. You can find more information on how it works [here](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/tools/toolsRepair.html).

However `nodetool repair` is very expensive, it is long and uses a lot of cpu, disk and network. There is this good [post](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/common-mistakes-and-misconceptions) about repair benefits and drawbacks.

Comment: As seen in the log, the top exception talks about a bad SSTable file and the bottom exception talks about a bad Commit Log file. So deleting those two files would fix it right? (as in let Cassandra start with data loss of course)

Comment: It is not quite a good way to proceed but I know no other   one. And yes Cassandra will start.

Answer (score 42):

Since you don't care about the data, removing files from \data\commitlogs should be easiest solution.

Answer (score 21):

This is how I fixed the problem with commit logs.
You should only do this if you don't care about preserving the state of your commit logs.

Try to restart cassandra using

`sudo systemctl restart cassandra`

Then I check

`systemctl status cassandra`

and see that the status is 'exited' so there is a problem. Check the logs for cassandra using

`sudo less /var/log/cassandra/system.log`

and see `org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLogReplayer$CommitLogReplayException: Could not read commit log descriptor in file /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-6-1498210233635.log`

Because I don't care about preserving the state of Cassandra I delete all of the commit logs and it now boots up fine

`sudo rm /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog*
sudo systemctl restart cassandra`

`systemctl status cassandra` (should confirm that it it now running)

Comment: This solution worked for me. Thank you for sharing it!

Answer (score 7):

Simply goes in log directory in cassandra and delete the log files.
It work fine....