# Cassandra 3.11 throwing error "Exiting due to error while processing commit log during initialization"

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I installed Cassandra using brew on mac, it was working fine for few days. But now it started throwing the error without changing anything in yaml file.

```
Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1': error(61, "Tried connecting to [('127.0.0.1', 9042)]. Last error: Connection refused")})
```

So I tried to update Cassandra using brew to 3.11. Now while starting Cassandra I am getting this error.

```
ERROR [main] 2017-09-20 12:52:02,732 JVMStabilityInspector.java:82 - Exiting due to error while processing commit log during initialization.
org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLogReadHandler$CommitLogReadException: Encountered bad header at position 157007 of commit log /usr/local/var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-6-1505888222471.log, with bad position but valid CRC
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLogSegmentReader$SegmentIterator.computeNext(CommitLogSegmentReader.java:113) [apache-cassandra-3.11.0.jar:3.11.0]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLogSegmentReader$SegmentIterator.computeNext(CommitLogSegmentReader.java:84) [apache-cassandra-3.11.0.jar:3.11.0]
    at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.tryToComputeNext(AbstractIterator.java:143) [guava-18.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.hasNext(AbstractIterator.java:138) [guava-18.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLogReader.readCommitLogSegment(CommitLogReader.java:190) [apache-cassandra-3.11.0.jar:3.11.0]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLogReader.readAllFiles(CommitLogReader.java:84) [apache-cassandra-3.11.0.jar:3.11.0]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLogReplayer.replayFiles(CommitLogReplayer.java:140) [apache-cassandra-3.11.0.jar:3.11.0]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLog.recoverFiles(CommitLog.java:177) [apache-cassandra-3.11.0.jar:3.11.0]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLog.recoverSegmentsOnDisk(CommitLog.java:158) [apache-cassandra-3.11.0.jar:3.11.0]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:325) [apache-cassandra-3.11.0.jar:3.11.0]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:600) [apache-cassandra-3.11.0.jar:3.11.0]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:689) [apache-cassandra-3.11.0.jar:3.11.0]
```

From this link [Cassandra: Exiting due to error while processing commit log during initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33304367/cassandra-exiting-due-to-error-while-processing-commit-log-during-initializatio)
I got some info about node tool repair. But even node tool repair is not working.

```
objc[15089]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_111.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java (0x10934b4c0) and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_111.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib (0x10abba4e0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
nodetool: Failed to connect to '127.0.0.1:7199' - ConnectException: 'Connection refused (Connection refused)'.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
commit log /usr/local/var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-6-1505888222471.log
```

It sounds like one of your commit log files got corrupted.  Remove that file, and restart.

"But even node tool repair is not working."

I wouldn't worry about that.  If you're on a single node cluster (ex: your own Mac), repair doesn't have any other nodes to stream data from, so it won't work anyway.